# How to create specific chapter style in book documentclass

Tags: sectioning, chapters

I am using the `book` documentclass for my thesis. The chapter titles are the normal ones but I would like to know is it is possible to change them to something more fancy, preferable without changing the documentclass.

In particular, I am interested to those chapter titles which, on the first page of every chapter, they have a solid black line on top (i.e., in the header), above which and flushed left is written "Chapter x" while, directly below that line and flushed right is the chapter name/title.

I have seen various theses written in this style although I cannot find which one it is.

I am aware of `fncychap`, `memoir` etc but the styles of those packages - at least the ones which I have seen - do not appeal to me.

If anyone is familiar with the style I described and knows a smooth way to do it within the documentclass `book`, I would be glad to know it.

If, for any reason whatsoever, this is incompatible with documentclass `book`, I would also like to know alternative solutions.

Answer (score 32):

The [`titlesec`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/titlesec) package allows you to easily customize the headings for the sectional units; a little example:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{titlesec} 
\usepackage{lipsum} % just to generate text for the example

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\bfseries\Large}
  {\filright\MakeUppercase{\chaptertitlename} \Huge\thechapter}
  {1ex}
  {\titlerule\vspace{1ex}\filleft}
  [\vspace{1ex}\titlerule]

\begin{document}

\chapter{Test Unnumbered Chapter}
\lipsum[1-2]
\chapter{Test Numbered Chapter}
\lipsum[1-2]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 14):

Have a look at [Vincent Zoonekynd’s](http://zoonek.free.fr/LaTeX/LaTeX_samples_chapter/0.html) web-pages. Here you will find 46 different chapter-styles. If you find one that is approximately what you are asking for, please tell me, and I will help you making the final touch up, if I have necessary skills.

Regarding compatibility; it depends on the other packages you are loading. If some of your style files modify the definition of chapter and sections, there may be compatibility issues.

You may also load the package [titlesec](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/titlesec) in your preamble, read the package’s manual, and start modifying the chapter definition yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Just adding to Gonzalo's answer above, as it is missing the actual title.

it should be

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{titlesec} 
\usepackage{lipsum} % just to generate text for the example

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\bfseries\Large}
  {\filright\MakeUppercase{\chaptertitlename} \Huge\thechapter}
  {1ex}
  {\titlerule\vspace{1ex}\filleft #1}
  [\vspace{1ex}\titlerule]

\begin{document}

\chapter{Test Unnumbered Chapter}
\lipsum[1-2]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! +1 as it answers the question but it would be nice if you could extend the code into a small, complete example that can compile so future readers can copy and paste your solution as it is, i.e. starting with `\documentclass{}` and ending with `\end{document}`, helps improve the site :)