# How do I remove "Chapter N" from the chapter titles of a book

Tags: header-footer

How do I remove "Chapter N" from the chapters when using the `book` document class?

This does not appear in the TOC (which I don't want, either).

But it appears at the beginning of a chapter, and on each page, in the header.

Comment: How are you producing your headers?

Comment: @GonzaloMedina: They appear automatically on each page that isn't a "new chapter" page - I guess because of the book mode.

Comment: What about the table of contents? Should the chapter entries remain numbered? What about sections, should they still carry the chapter number as a prefix?

Comment: @GonzaloMedina: Yes, to both questions.

Comment: Please see my updated answer.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by the "page headers"?

Comment: If you want unnumbered chapters in the book class, and if you're not tweeking the appearance of your chapter titles, you should use the `\chapter*` command, not the `\chapter` command.

Comment: @MarcvanDongen the problem with `\chapter*` is that Emanuel still wants numbered chapter entries in the ToC and chapter numbers as prefixes for lower sectional units (see the first comments).

Comment: @einpoklum: Check out the edit for a dump showing the header.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina: Where did you answer go? It was correct, and now it works. Check out the edit to the question.

Comment: @EmanuelBerg I deleted it, since I wasn't sure it had helped. I've now un-deleted it.

Comment: Emanuel, please place your final solution as a separate answer or just drop it, now that @GonzaloMedina's answer is undeleted.

Comment: @einpoklum: What do you mean? I accepted his answer, because it was the source of the code snippet that did the work, however, for any future reader of this question it is beneficial just getting the quick "fix", because not everyone has the time/interest to really understand why and how something is a solution.

Comment: @einpoklum: Done, perhaps a bit silly but sure, details are important.

Comment: I don't understand this. What's the point of providing good answers with several valid options?

Comment: @GonzaloMedina: I think you should have the credit with my comments in the question, as it were, but einpoklum seemed very certain so I did as he told me, as I don't think this is anything to waste time on.

Comment: So my answer is a waste of time?  I certainly think it is now that I read your comment.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina: No, a waste of time to make a new answer out of my comments (that I previously had put in the question), and accept that answer, as einpoklum told me.

Comment: I don't know, but it seems a little redundant. What's the point then? Every user can then write his/her own answer and accept it. I don't know if this is the way things are supposed to be.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina: I agree, I thought it was correct the way it was, but please, let us not waste our short lives on this, OK?

Comment: @EmanuelBerg sure :-)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**Partial solution**

Thanks to einpoklum's [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/120741/9452), I found that this

```
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\bfseries\Large}                                            
{\filright}
{1ex}{}[]
```

solves the problem for the chapter start.

But the page headers remain.

**Full solution**

It appears this did it. Thanks to Gonzalo Medina, for his [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/120743/9452), from where I exerted the code.

```
\usepackage[pagestyles]{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]{\normalfont\bfseries}{}{0pt}{\Huge}
\newpagestyle{mystyle}
{\sethead[\thepage][][\chaptertitle]{}{}{\thepage}}
\pagestyle{mystyle}
```

Now it looks the way I like. (The screenshots got dusty, for some reason.)

[chapter http://user.it.uu.se/~embe8573/chapter.png](http://user.it.uu.se/~embe8573/chapter.png)
[header http://user.it.uu.se/~embe8573/header.png](http://user.it.uu.se/~embe8573/header.png)

Answer (score 30):

With the help of [`titlesec`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/titlesec):

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\normalfont\bfseries}{}{0pt}{\Large}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Test Chapter}
\lipsum[3]

\end{document}
```

Without titlesec:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter
\def\@makechapterhead#1{%
  \vspace*{50\p@}%
  {\parindent \z@ \raggedright \normalfont
    \interlinepenalty\@M
    \Large \bfseries #1\par\nobreak
    \vskip 40\p@
  }}
\def\@makeschapterhead#1{%
  \vspace*{50\p@}%
  {\parindent \z@ \raggedright
    \normalfont
    \interlinepenalty\@M
    \Large \bfseries  #1\par\nobreak
    \vskip 40\p@
  }}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\chapter{Test Chapter}
\lipsum[3]

\end{document}
```

[image]

To customize the headers/footers, one option is to use the [`fancyhdr`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr) package; a little example, suppressing the prefix "Chapter N" from the default headers, and with the text in normal case (no upper-case):

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\normalfont\bfseries}{}{0pt}{\Large}

\pagestyle{fancy}

\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[RE]{\leftmark}
\fancyhead[LO]{\rightmark}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\thepage}
\renewcommand\headrulewidth{0pt}
\renewcommand\chaptermark[1]{\markboth{#1}{}} 
\renewcommand\sectionmark[1]{\markright{\thesection.\ #1}}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Test Chapter}
\section{Test Section}
\lipsum[1-20]

\end{document}
```

Another option for the headers/footers is to use the `pagestyles` option for `titlesec` and design the desired style:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[pagestyles]{titlesec}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\normalfont\bfseries}{}{0pt}{\Large}
\newpagestyle{mystyle}{
  \sethead[\thepage][][\chaptertitle]{\thesection~\sectiontitle}{}{\thepage}
}
\pagestyle{mystyle}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Test Chapter}
\section{Test Section}
\lipsum[1-20]

\end{document}
```

Comment: I used without using titles but the output is showing some paragraph which  was not supposed to be shown how to remove it?

Comment: The problem i've got is i want appendices, to be labelled but not chapters.

Answer (score 3):

The 'Chapter N' text is the value of the `\@chapapp` macro, defined in the book document class.

But... no need to tinker with that directly. See

[How to create specific chapter style in book documentclass](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/73421/5640)

it refers you to the [titlesec](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/titlesec) package and to [these](http://zoonek.free.fr/LaTeX/LaTeX_samples_chapter/0.html) pages, with which you
can change the chapter heading style. One of the things you can do, specifically, is play with the way the number is displayed.

Comment: Thanks, that solved half the problem. Check out the [edit](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/120740/9452) I just made.

Comment: `\thechapter` just produces the representation for the counter; the string "Chapter" comes from the internal `\@chapapp` command.

Answer (score 3):

I found adding an asterisk after chapter works, like this: \chapter*{Introduction}

Found on https://www-users.york.ac.uk/~pjh503/LaTeX/text.html

It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

To remove the "Chapter n", just need to add `\setcounter{secnumdepth}{-1}` before the `\begin{document}`

***Source:***

The ctan [package documentation](https://ctan.org/pkg/book) says

> @chapter | This macro is called when we have a numbered chapter. When secnumdepth is larger than −1 and, in the book class, @mainmatter is true, we display the chapter number. We also inform the user that a new chapter is about to be typeset by writing a message to the terminal.

```
%% example code in the documentation
790 \def\@chapter[#1]#2{\ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
791 ⟨book⟩ \if@mainmatter
792 \refstepcounter{chapter}%
793 \typeout{\@chapapp\space\thechapter.}%
794 \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}%
795 {\protect\numberline{\thechapter}#1}%
796 ⟨∗book⟩
797 \else
798 \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#1}%
799 \fi
800 ⟨/book⟩
801 \else
802 \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#1}%
803 \fi
```

For example, if you need to remove "Part N" for \part, then you change it for `\setcounter{secnumdepth}{-2}` and so on.