# How to Get rid of "Chapter N" without ruin the fontsize, and Remove the numbering "N title chapter" on the TOC

Tags: table-of-contents, chapters, single-sided, book-class

Actually i have seen all possibilities similar questions one by one. They have similar problem, but my problem is more complicated. So, here is my problem:

I want to remove "Chapter N" when i'm using:

```
\chapter{\textbf{Test Chapter}}
```

I'm not going to use `\chapter*{...}` because this makes my section start with `0.1 Section` instead of `1.1 Section`. I have seen this [link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/120743/221368), and tried to use it using `\titlesec` to remove my `Chapter N`.

This is my code before i changed anything, (Btw, i wrote the important part of my code only so you can focus on it):

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,oneside,openany]{book}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
    {\normalfont\bfseries\centering}
    {\chaptertitlename \thechapter}{12pt}{}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{10pt}{10pt}
```

This is my code after i tried to remove `Chapter N`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,oneside,openany]{book}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
    {\normalfont\bfseries\centering}{}{0pt}{\Large}
    {\chaptertitlename \thechapter}{12pt}{}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{10pt}{10pt}
```

and actually it removes the `Chapter N` like i wanted before. The point is, i only adding `{}{0pt}{\Large}` after `{\normalfont\bfseries\centering}`. And because of this, i got 2 problems here:

First Problem:

My fontsize was changed and getting bigger, and i got error message refers to `{\chaptertitlename \thechapter}{12pt}{}`

You can see before and after removing `Chapter N` in the following link below:

[BEFORE REMOVING CHAPTER](https://ibb.co/4f90jr3) and [AFTER REMOVING CHAPTER](https://ibb.co/QFLWHQT)

This is my error message: [link image](https://ibb.co/xgp91BR) Even though i\ve tried to place after `\begin{document}`

My Goal is i can remove `Chapter N` using simple code, without any error messages, and not changes the fontsize that i've changed before that is 12pt.

Second Problem:

This is not actually a problem that i got after using my code as i said before, i mean it's another problem and i want to remove numbering `N title chapter` on the TOC. Here is my [current output](https://ibb.co/xfLfnbs). As you can see, there is a number in the front `1 BAB. 1 PENDAHULUAN` and i want to remove `1` on the front becomes `BAB 1. PENDAHULUAN` like this [output](https://ibb.co/jfZ2Xn5).

I really appreciate your answer. Please help me and Thanks in advance.

EDIT: This is my MWE

(Main tex file)

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,oneside,openany]{book}
\usepackage{pgf, tikz}
\usepackage[a4paper, inner=4cm, outer=3cm, top=4cm, bottom=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}
\usepackage{tocbibind}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\fancyhf{}
\cfoot{\thepage}
\linespread{1.5}
\pagestyle{plain}
\renewcommand\cftchapdotsep{\cftdotsep}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
    {\normalfont\bfseries\centering}
    {\chaptertitlename \thechapter}{12pt}{}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{10pt}{10pt}

\renewcommand{\contentsname}{DAFTAR ISI}
\renewcommand{\listtablename}{DAFTAR TABEL}
\renewcommand{\listfigurename}{DAFTAR GAMBAR}

\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\null\protect\hfill{Halaman}\protect\par}
\setlength\parindent{1.25cm} 
\begin{document}

\clearpage
\thispagestyle{empty}

\frontmatter %

\pagestyle{fancy}   
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\include{cover1}
\include{cover2}


\mainmatter %
\include{bab1}

\end{document}
```

(File: bab1)

```
\chapter{\textbf{BAB 1. PENDAHULUAN}} 
%TEXT HERE
\section{Latar Belakang} 
%TEXT HERE
```

Comment: Question: Do you want the chapter number to not appear at all? If so, why do you want sections numbered Chap.Sec (e.g. 1.1)?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please provide a complete example which starts at `\documentclass` and ends with `\end{document}` and can reproduce your problem. By convention an example like that is called an [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Comment: @DonaldArseneau Thanks for answering. Actually this is TOC template from my college, so after Chapter begins, the sections must have numbered like 1.1; 1.2; 2.1; 2.2 and so on.

Comment: @muzimuzhiZ Hi, thank you 4 ur suggestion. Please see my edit.

Comment: @DonaldArseneau btw, yes, i don't want the chapter. So i want to remove the "Chapter 1" above the title chapter. It works with my code as i mentioned in my question, but it ruined the fontsize of All ToC, LoF, LoT, and Chapter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

```
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
    {\normalfont\bfseries\centering}
    {\chaptertitlename \thechapter}{12pt}{}
```

to

```
\titleformat{\chapter}[block]
    {\normalfont\bfseries\centering}
    {}{0pt}{}
```

- In `display` format, there is a linebreak between `\chaptertitlename \thechapter` and the chapter title. Since you don't need `Chapter N`, I replace `display` by `block`.
- The separation between `Chapter N` and chapter title is set to zero `0pt` as well.
- You don't need to use `\textbf` in `\chapter`, the chapter title is already in bold (set by `\bfseries` in `\titleformat{\chapter}...`).

For detailed syntax and documentation of `\titleformat`, see [`titlesec` manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/titlesec/titlesec.pdf), sec. 3.1.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,oneside,openany]{book}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[a4paper, inner=4cm, outer=3cm, top=4cm, bottom=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}
\usepackage{tocbibind}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\fancyhf{}
\cfoot{\thepage}
\linespread{1.5}
\pagestyle{plain}
\renewcommand\cftchapdotsep{\cftdotsep}
\titleformat{\chapter}[block]
    {\normalfont\bfseries\centering}
    {}{0pt}{}

\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{10pt}{10pt}

\renewcommand{\contentsname}{DAFTAR ISI}
\renewcommand{\listtablename}{DAFTAR TABEL}
\renewcommand{\listfigurename}{DAFTAR GAMBAR}

\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\null\protect\hfill{Halaman}\protect\par}
\setlength\parindent{1.25cm} 
\begin{document}

\frontmatter
\tableofcontents

\pagestyle{fancy}

\mainmatter
\chapter{BAB 1. PENDAHULUAN} 
%TEXT HERE
\section{Latar Belakang}
%TEXT HERE

\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]

#### Update

As requested in [comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/555778/how-to-get-rid-of-chapter-n-without-ruin-the-fontsize-and-remove-the-numberin/556796?noredirect=1#comment1403997_556796), to hide the chapter number in `\tableofcontents`, add following code to preamble, after `tocloft` is loaded.

```
\usepackage{xpatch}
% patch the \l@chapter redefined by tocloft package, hide chapter number
\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd\l@chapter
  {\cftchapfont}
  {\let\numberline\@gobble\cftchapfont}
  {}{\fail}
\makeatother
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It works. Maybe one last question please. So, since i'm using `\chapter{...}`, in the ToC would printed as `1 BAB 1. PENDAHULUAN, 2 BAB 2. TITLE CHAPTER, 3 BAB 3. TITLE CHAPTER` and so on. And i want to remove the numbering on the front (the number `1, 2, 3,...` ), so it becomes `BAB 1. PENDAHULUAN, BAB 2. TITLE CHAPTER, BAB 3. TITLE CHAPTER` printed on the ToC. Can you help me? Again, many thanks for you.

Comment: @user516076 Only hide for chapter and reserve for section and lower level sectioning titles in toc?

Comment: only the chapter. I want to remove the number behind the chapter. Thanks

Comment: @user516076 See the "Update" part in my answer.

Comment: Unfortunately i got error message File 'l3backend-pdfmode.def' not found. {\sys^load_backend { } }

Comment: @user516076 You need to update your LaTeX distribution. Either update packages (especially, install `l3backend`), or install a latest distribution.