# Remove the number behind the chapter on the ToC

Tags: table-of-contents

For example, using `\chapter{INTRODUCTION}` will be printed as

```
1 INTRODUCTION...............x
```

I want to remove the number `1` behind the chapter, so the output on the ToC would be:

```
INTRODUCTION................x
```

Note: `x` is a page number.

My MWE is :

```
\documentclass{a4paper, 12pt, oneside, openany}{book}
\usepackage[a4paper, inner=4cm, outer=3cm, top=4cm, bottom=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Chapter 1. INTRODUCTION}
\section{Section Name}
\blindtext
\section{Section Name}
\blindtext
\chapter{Chapter 2. BACKGROUND}
\section{Section Name}
\blindtext
\section{Section Name}
\blindtext

\end{document}
```

Comment: Is the introduction still expected to have a number in the text? Or should it be gone in both cases? BTW: you're missing a `}` after `book`

Comment: @daleif Thanks for the correction. In the text, it should be shown as `Chapter 1. INTRODUCTION` as well. (No number behind the title).

Comment: Your document confuses me a lot. Why are you writing `Chapter 1`, `Chapter 2` by hand? That makes no sense.

Comment: @daleif yea. I won't use `\chapter*{...}` because it makes the first section start with `0.1, 0.2 ....` instead of `1.1, 1.2, 1.3`. And an easy way to get `1.1, 1.2, 1.3` is using `\chapter{...}` and writing chapter by hand.

Comment: And actually i about to use `\section*{...}` to avoid the zero starts. But that's a bad idea cuz it's not automatic and another reason. I just want to remove that number behind the title of chapter, that's all. Please help me.

Comment: You're requirement does not make any sense at all. And neither does writing where by hand. BTW remember that the chapter counter can be set by hand, fx stepped one bia `\refstepcounter{chapter}` or `\stepcounter{chapter}`

Comment: Oh ok. I've tried `\stepcounter{chapter}` and it doesn't work for chapter 2

Comment: If i use `\refstepcounter{chapter}` or `\stepcounter{chapter}`, the section only shows `1.1, 1.2....` and can't show `2.1, 2.2`. That's why i'm using `\chapter{...}`

Comment: @daleif Sorry if it confuses you. Maybe this can help you to understand what i mean. Link: https://ibb.co/n80BsFN . As you can see, the output on the ToC only shows the title without number, and the section. This is why i'm using `\chapter{....}` and   `section{...}`. I managed to fix the text ouput on the mainmatter, so all i care about is only to remove the number behind the chapter.

Comment: Related: the "Update" part of this answer: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/556796/79060

Comment: That only shows the toc, please show images of some of the relevant pages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can influence the appearance of the titles in the table of contents with the `titletoc` package. This allows you to remove the number.

The command for this is `\titlecontents`. See the comments in the code below for a description of the arguments of this command. See also the [package documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/titlesec/titlesec.pdf).

MWE (note that I removed the manual 'Chapter n.' parts of the `\chapter` commands):

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, oneside, openany]{book}
\usepackage[a4paper, inner=4cm, outer=3cm, top=4cm, bottom=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\titlecontents{chapter}% redefine chapter toc appearance
[1.5em]% left margin
{}% code before starting the title, here empty
{\hspace*{-2.3em}\bfseries}% format: shift a bit left and boldface, no number
{\hspace*{-2.3em}\bfseries}% format for \chapter*, not really needed for the MWE but added for completeness
{\titlerule*[1pc]{.}\contentspage}% dotted line and page number

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{INTRODUCTION}
\section{Section Name}
\blindtext
\section{Section Name}
\blindtext
\chapter{BACKGROUND}
\section{Section Name}
\blindtext
\section{Section Name}
\blindtext

\end{document}
```

Result in TOC:

[image]

In the document:

[image]

If you also want to change the appearance in the document then you can use the `titlesec` package which is closely related to `titletoc` with very similar syntax. The command for changing the title in the document is `\titleformat`. See the comments in the code below for a description of the arguments of this command.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, oneside, openany]{book}
\usepackage[a4paper, inner=4cm, outer=3cm, top=4cm, bottom=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\titlecontents{chapter}% redefine chapter toc appearance
[1.5em]% left margin
{}% code before starting the title, here empty
{\hspace*{-2.3em}\bfseries}% format: shift a bit left and boldface, no number
{\hspace*{-2.3em}\bfseries}% format for \chapter*, not really needed for the MWE but added for completeness
{\titlerule*[1pc]{.}\contentspage}% dotted line and page number

\titleformat{\chapter}% change format of chapter in the document
{\huge\bfseries}% huge font and bold
{Chapter \thechapter}% the word Chapter followed by the chapter number
{1em}%horizontal space between 'Chapter n' and the chapter title
{}% code after the title, here empty

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{INTRODUCTION}
\section{Section Name}
\blindtext
\section{Section Name}
\blindtext
\chapter{BACKGROUND}
\section{Section Name}
\blindtext
\section{Section Name}
\blindtext

\end{document}
```

The TOC is the same, but in the document a chapter is now as follows:

[image]