# Indexing problem with the table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents

I'm writting my dissertation and have found a problem with my table of contents: all sections are numbered zero

[image]

How can I number the sections without the zeros? Below is a minimum working version of my code

```
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[a4paper,top=3cm,left=3cm,right=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[brazilian]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\DeclareMathOperator\arctanh{arctanh}
\DeclareMathOperator\diag{diag}
\DeclareMathOperator\sign{sign}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[rawfloats=true]{floatrow}
\graphicspath{{Figuras/}}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage[small,bf]{caption}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{MnSymbol}
\usepackage{dsfont}
\usepackage{scalerel,stackengine}
\stackMath
\newcommand\reallywidehat[1]{%
\savestack{\tmpbox}{\stretchto{%
  \scaleto{%
    \scalerel*[\widthof{\ensuremath{#1}}]{\kern-.6pt\bigwedge\kern-.6pt}%
    {\rule[-\textheight/2]{1ex}{\textheight}}%WIDTH-LIMITED BIG WEDGE
  }{\textheight}% 
}{0.5ex}}%
\stackon[1pt]{#1}{\tmpbox}%
}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{mathbbol}
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}

 
\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheorem*{resumindo}{Resumindo}
\newtheorem*{definicao}{Definição}
\newtheorem{propriedade}{Propriedade}
\newtheorem{proposicao}{Proposição}
\newtheorem{provaprop}{Prova da Proposição}
\newtheorem{teorema}{Teorema}
\newtheorem{prova}{Prova}




\title{}
\author{ }
\date{}



\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.4}
\linespread{1.3}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{center}


    {\fontsize{16}{16} \selectfont Universidade de S\~ao Paulo \\}
    \vspace{0.1cm}
    {\fontsize{16}{16} \selectfont Instituto de F\'{i}sica}
    \vspace{3.3cm}

    {\fontsize{22}{22}\selectfont Titulo\par}
    \vspace{2cm}


    {\fontsize{18}{18}\selectfont Nome\par}

    \vspace{2cm}

\end{center}

\leftskip 6cm
\begin{flushright}  
\leftskip 6cm
Orientador(a): Prof. Dr.  

\underline{ \hskip 5cm  } 
\leftskip 6cm

\end{flushright}    

    \vspace{0.8cm}    



\par
\leftskip 6cm
\noindent {Disserta\c{c}\~{a}o de mestrado apresentada ao Instituto de F\'{i}sica da Universidade de S\~{a}o Paulo, como requisito parcial para a obten\c{c}\~{a}o do t\'{i}tulo de Mestre em Ci\^{e}ncias.}
\par
\leftskip 0cm
\vskip 2cm



\noindent Banca Examinadora: \\
Prof(a). Dr(a). Nome do(a) Professor(a) (institui\c{c}\~{a}o de trabalho) \\
Prof(a). Dr(a). Nome do(a) Professor(a) (institui\c{c}\~{a}o de trabalho) \\
\vspace{2.4cm}


\begin{center}
    {S\~ao Paulo \\  2021}
\end{center}
\clearpage


\tableofcontents
\newpage




\section{AAAAA}
aaaa
\section{BBBBB}

aa


\subsection{bbbbb}
aaaa

\subsection{ccccc}

aaaa
\subsubsection{ddddd}
aaaaa
\section{CCCC}
aaaa




\begin{appendices}
\section{AAAAA}
aaaa


\section{BBBBB}
aaaa

\end{appendices}









\end{document}
```

Comment: Which documentclass do you use? Most like it is one that expects chapters as the first sectioning level.

Comment: \documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside]{book}

Comment: This realy solves the problem, but I didn't want the "Chapter 1" part showing before the name of the chapter, is there a way to change it?

Comment: [How do I remove "Chapter N" from the chapter titles of a book](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/120740/134144) might help.

Comment: Thank you ver much! This solves my problem!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `book` (and `report`) class the section numbers are preceded by the chapter number. As you aren't using `\chapter` in your MWE then the current value of the chapter number is 0.

If you insist on not using `\chapter` then change the section number representation by:

```
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}
```

On the other hand, if you are not using chapters then why not use the `article` class or similar and you won't have to change anything.

Hopefully the following MWE will show you what you might want to do.

```
% secnumprob.tex  SE 580362
\documentclass{book}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}} % no chapter number used

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter*{A chapter} % unnumbered, just the title in the text
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{A chapter} % add the title to the ToC
\section{First section}
\section{Second}
\subsection{A subsection}
\end{document}
```

[image]