# Why the chapter name and section name are not coming alternately in the header?

Tags: header-footer, books

**MWE:**

```
\documentclass[lang=en,11pt]{elegantbook}
\usepackage{lipsum}


\title{Book Title}
\subtitle{Chapter and section at header alternatively}

\author{No author name given}
\institute{ABC}
\date{February 10, 2020}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\frontmatter
\tableofcontents

\mainmatter
\chapter{First Chapter}
\lipsum[1]

\section{First Ection}
\lipsum[1-20]

\subsection{First Ection}
\lipsum[1]
\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

How can I get chapter name and section alternatively in [elegantbook](https://github.com/ElegantLaTeX/ElegantBook/blob/master/elegantbook.cls)?

Comment: +1 For the nice MWE!

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner I like very much your comment for the "nice MWE": ihhihihihihiihhih :-) +1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Maybe this helps, I just used the option `twoside` in the document class.
- According to the [manual](https://ctan.org/pkg/elegantbook), the template is "[...] based on the Standard LATEX book class, so the **options of book class work** as well".

[image]

---

```
\documentclass[lang=en,11pt, twoside]{elegantbook} % <-- Modified
\usepackage{lipsum}

\title{Book Title}
\subtitle{Chapter and section at header alternatively}

\author{No author name given}
\institute{ABC}
\date{February 10, 2020}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\frontmatter
\tableofcontents

\mainmatter
\chapter{First Chapter}
\lipsum[1]

\section{First Ection}
\lipsum[1-20]

\subsection{First Ection}
\lipsum[1]
\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: @ Dr.ManuelKuehner  Thank you very much for your answer. If I would like to get chapter name with chapter number like "1 First Chapter" not like "Chapter 1 First Chapter", what to do? Section at header is good.

Comment: Please ask a new question. But before you do that, do a Google search regarding the book class in Latex.

Comment: @user239457 In case you were not pinged with my previous comment. BTW, I go offline now, it's 10:40 PM local time for me :). Just a guess, you are probably interested in https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/120740.