# How do I make chapter header from number and title only, without including "chapter n" in document class book

Tags: chapters, titles

I am trying to get a chapter header where I include the chapter number to the title without the "chapter n" before the chapter title.

This thread helped to remove the "chapter n", but I don't know how to include the numbering into the header.

Here an example with my current output. Desired output would show "1 Foo" (Or even better: "1. Foo") etc

```
\documentclass{book}

% from https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/120740/how-do-i-remove-chapter-n-from-the-chapter-titles-of-a-book
\makeatletter
\def\@makechapterhead#1{%
  \vspace*{50\p@}%
  {\parindent \z@ \raggedright \normalfont
    \interlinepenalty\@M
    \Large \bfseries #1\par\nobreak
    \vskip 40\p@
  }}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\chapter{Foo}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default definition of `\@makechapterhead` is this:

```
\vspace *{50\p@ }%
    {\parindent \z@ \raggedright \normalfont
    \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne \if@mainmatter%
        \huge \bfseries \@chapapp \space \thechapter%
        \par \nobreak \vskip 20\p@
    \fi \fi%
    \interlinepenalty\@M
    \Huge \bfseries #1\par \nobreak%
    \vskip 40\p@
}
```

Splitting the difference between that and the definition you're using, you might try this:

```
\documentclass{book}

% from https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/120740/how-do-i-remove-chapter-n-from-the-chapter-titles-of-a-book
\makeatletter
\def\@makechapterhead#1{%
  \vspace*{50\p@}%
  {\parindent \z@ \raggedright \normalfont
    \interlinepenalty\@M
    \Huge \bfseries
    \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne \if@mainmatter \thechapter. \fi \fi
    #1\par\nobreak
    \vskip 40\p@
  }}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\chapter{Foo}

\end{document}
```

[image: 1. foo]

Or you could use `\Large` instead of `\Huge` to be more like your original definition, or `\huge` for something in between.