# Chapter Name not appearing

Tags: sectioning, chapters, titlesec

I wanted to style the chapter name. I referred the following link :
[how-to-create-specific-chapter-style-in-book-documentclass](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/73421/how-to-create-specific-chapter-style-in-book-documentclass)

Here is my code:

```
%Template for Technical Document
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage{titlesec}
% Can also use centering, or hcentering

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\bfseries\Large}
  {\filright\MakeUppercase{\chaptertitlename}\Huge\thechapter}
  {1ex}
  {\titlerule\vspace{1ex}\filleft}
  [\vspace{1ex}\titlerule]

\begin{document}
\chapter{Install Backtrack on an Android Device}
\section{What is Backtrack?}
BackTrack is a distribution designed by Jason Dennis based on the Ubuntu Linux distribution aimed at digital forensics and penetration testing use. BackTrack provides users with easy access to a comprehensive and large collection of security-related tools ranging from port scanners to Security Audit. Support for Live CD and Live USB functionality allows users to boot BackTrack directly from portable media without requiring installation, though permanent installation to hard disk and network is also an option.\par
\end{document}
```

I get the following output:
[image]

After using the `explicit` option in `titlesec` and numbering the chapter as per the solution given, I get this output:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're loading the [`titlesec`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/titlesec) package twice- only the first instance actually counts, the second one is ignored.

When you use the `explicit` option for the [`titlesec`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/titlesec) package, you *have* to specify the heading title using `#1`.

As such, you could use, for example,

```
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\bfseries\Large}
  {\filright\MakeUppercase{\chaptertitlename}\Huge\thechapter}
  {1ex}
  {\titlerule\vspace{1ex}\filleft #1}
  [\vspace{1ex}\titlerule]
```

or else remove the `explicit` option and simply load the `titlesec` package using

```
\usepackage{titlesec}
```

in which case, you can stick with your original code.

Comment: How do I align the chapter title?filleft or filcenter doesn't seem to work?I want to center align the title

Comment: When I use explicit option and add ~#1 to the code as mentioned , I get illegeal parameter error??? @cmhughes

Comment: I have edited my question ..

Comment: @subhamsoni I see that you have edited your question- however, it still does not contain your desired output. It looks like Harish Kumar edited my answer as he was able to predict what you wanted. In the future, please make sure your question contains enough details :)

Comment: Sure @cmhughes...