# Title of the chapter "in the center" arabtext

Tags: chapters, arabic, arabtex

i want to obtain the title of the chapter in the center of the page

here a minimal example

Thank you

```
\documentclass[12pt]{arabbook} %{arabart},oneside
\usepackage{amsfonts,amssymb,amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{arqam}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{color}
\novocalize
%\parskip 0mm
%\setcounter{page}{1}\setcounter{chapter}{1}
\mathchardef\cap="225C
%\dominitoc \linespread{1.5} \setlength{\hoffset}{-18pt}
\textwidth=17.5truecm
\hoffset=-2truecm 
\textheight=24truecm
\voffset=-3truecm 
\newcommand{\vc}[3]{\overset{#2}{\underset{#3}{#1}}}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter 
\newcommand{\arabic@words}[1]{
    \ifcase#1\or 
    Al'awl\or 
    Al_tAny\or 
    Al_tAlt\or
    AlrAb`\or
    Al_hms\or
    AlsAds
    \else\@ctrerr\fi}
\newcommand*\arabicwords[1]{\expandafter\arabic@words\csname c@#1\endcsname}
\def \a@chapter [#1]#2{% numbered chapter
    \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
    \if@mainmatter
    \refstepcounter {chapter}%
    \typeout {\@chapapp \space \thechapter.}%
    \addcontentsline {toc}{chapter}%
    {\protect\numberline {\@chapapp\space\arabicwords{chapter}:}\protect\RL {#1}}%
    \else \addcontentsline {toc}{chapter}{\protect\RL {#1}}%
    \fi          
    \else \addcontentsline {toc}{chapter}{\protect\RL {#1}}%
    \fi
    \chaptermark{\RL {#1}}%
    \addtocontents {lof}{\protect\addvspace {10\p@}}%
    \addtocontents {lot}{\protect\addvspace {10\p@}}%
    \if@twocolumn \@topnewpage [\a@makechapterhead {#2}]%
    \else \a@makechapterhead {#2}\a@afterheading
    \fi 
    \tracingmacros 0
    \test@token }

\newcommand{\ahhrule}{\leavevmode\leaders\hrule height 5pt\hfill\kern\z@}
\def\a@makechapterhead #1{% make heading with number
\null \vskip 50\p@
\begingroup \let \end \a@@par \a@@centering \interlinepenalty\@M
\ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
\if@mainmatter
        \edef \thechapter {\LR{\ahhrule}\@chapapp \space\arabicwords{chapter} \LR{\ahhrule}}%
        \huge \nashbf \set@arabfont \test@token {\thechapter } \end
        %\nobreak \vskip 10\p@
\fi\fi 
\hrule width \linewidth height 1pt \vskip10pt
        \Huge \nashbf \set@arabfont \test@token #1 \end
\vskip10pt\hrule width \linewidth height 1pt
\nobreak \vskip 40\p@
\endgroup }    

\def \a@l@chapter #1#2{% for arabic mode
    \ifnum \c@tocdepth >\m@ne
    \addpenalty {-\@highpenalty }\addvspace {1.0em plus\p@ }
    \@tempdima 4em 
    \begin{arabtext}
        \hskip .7\@tempdima #1 \hfill  \LR{#2}
    \end{arabtext}
    \penalty\@highpenalty
    \fi }

\at@arabtext{%
    \def \l@section #1#2{% for arabic mode
        \ifnum \c@tocdepth >\z@
        \addpenalty {\@secpenalty }
        \@tempdima 2.8em 
        \begin{arabtext}
            \hskip \@tempdima #1 \LR{\dotfill}\LR{#2}
        \end{arabtext}
        \penalty\@secpenalty
        \fi }}
\at@arabtext{%
    \def \l@subsection #1#2{% for arabic mode
        \ifnum \c@tocdepth >\z@
        \addpenalty {\@secpenalty }
        \@tempdima 2.8em 
        \begin{arabtext}
            \hskip \@tempdima #1 \LR{\dotfill}\LR{#2}
        \end{arabtext}
        \penalty\@secpenalty
        \fi }}
\at@arabtext{%
    \def \l@subsubsection #1#2{% for arabic mode
        \ifnum \c@tocdepth >\z@
        \addpenalty {\@secpenalty }
        \@tempdima 2.8em 
        \begin{arabtext}
            \hskip \@tempdima #1 \LR{\dotfill}\LR{#2}
        \end{arabtext}
        \penalty\@secpenalty
        \fi }}
\makeatother

\renewcommand{\thesection}{\LR\arabic{section}}
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\LR\arabic{section}.\LR\arabic{subsection}}
\renewcommand{\thesubsubsection}{\LR\arabic{section}.\LR\arabic{subsection}.\LR\arabic{subsubsection}}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}


\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{1.5pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{1.5pt}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1}



\begin{document}
\begin{arabtext}


\tableofcontents

\chapter{mkdmT}
\newpage


\end{arabtext}
\end{document}
```

where fichier arqam is:

```
\typeout{ArqAm Document Style `arqAm' <25 sb.tmr 99>.}
\catcode`\@=11
%%%%%
\ifa@book
% 'a.dyf mA yly 4 'as.tr:
\renewcommand\thesection%
{\LR{\@arabic\c@section.\@arabic\c@chapter}}
%t.gyiyr 220698
\renewcommand\thesubsection %
{\LR{\@arabic\c@subsection.\@arabic\c@section.\@arabic\c@chapter}}
\renewcommand\thesubsubsection % 'a.dyf 'amryn al-sAbq w-al-lA.hq
{\LR{\@arabic\c@subsubsection.\@arabic\c@subsection.\@arabic\c@section.%
\@arabic\c@chapter}}
%   220698
\fi
%%%
\ifa@article
\renewcommand\thesection {\LR{\@arabic\c@section}}  %t.gyiyr 220698
\renewcommand\thesubsection {\LR{\@arabic\c@subsection.\@arabic\c@section} }
\renewcommand\thesubsubsection % 'a.dyf 'amryn al-sAbq w-al-lA.hq
{\LR{\@arabic\c@subsubsection.\@arabic\c@subsection.\@arabic\c@section}
}
\fi
%    ****************************************
%    *             SECTIONS                 *
%    ****************************************

\def \a@c@section {\a@startsection
{section}{1}{\z@}{-3.5ex plus-1ex minus -.2ex}{2.3ex plus.2ex}%
%{\reset@font \Large\setnashbf }}
{\tr@ceoff \reset@font \Large \tr@ceon \setnashbf }}

\def \a@c@subsection {\a@startsection
{subsection}{2}{\z@}{-3.25ex plus-1ex minus-.2ex}{-1.5ex plus.2ex}%
%{\reset@font \large\setnashbf }}
{\tr@ceoff \reset@font \large \tr@ceon \setnashbf }}

\def \a@c@subsubsection {\a@startsection
{subsubsection}{3}{\z@}{-3.25ex plus -1ex minus-.2ex}{-1.5ex plus.2ex}%
%{\reset@font \normalsize\setnashbf }}
{\tr@ceoff \reset@font \normalsize \tr@ceon \setnashbf }}

\def \a@c@paragraph {\a@startsection
{paragraph}{4}{\z@}{3.25ex plus1ex minus.2ex}{-1em}%
%{\reset@font \normalsize\setnashbf }}
{\tr@ceoff \reset@font \normalsize \tr@ceon\setnashbf }}

\def\a@c@subparagraph {\a@startsection
{subparagraph}{5}{\parindent}{3.25ex plus1ex minus .2ex}{-1em}%
%{\reset@font \normalsize\setnashbf }}
{\tr@ceoff \reset@font \normalsize \tr@ceon\setnashbf }}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%240999
\def\a@sect #1#2#3#4#5#6[#7]#8{% Arabic mode
\ifnum #2 > \c@secnumdepth \let \@svsec \@empty
\else \refstepcounter{#1}%
    \edef \@svsec {\hskip 1em \nxp\RL {\csname the#1\endcsname}}%
\fi \@tempskipa #5\relax \ifdim \@tempskipa > \z@
    \begingroup \let \end \a@@par
        #6\relax \set@arabfont % style
            \a@hangfrom {\hskip #3\relax \@svsec }% section number
        \test@token #8 \end
    \endgroup
    \csname #1mark\endcsname {\RL {#7}}% 161099
        \addcontentsline {toc}{#1}%
        {\ifnum #2 > \c@secnumdepth \else
        \protect\numberline {\csname the#1\endcsname }\fi
        \protect\RL {#7}}%
\else \def \@svsechd % saved head, executed by \everypar
{\putwordb@x {#6\xpa\RL{#8}% $\bullet\hspace{-2truemm}-$}%
\@svsec\hskip #3\relax}%
        \csname #1mark\endcsname {\RL {#7}}%
    \addcontentsline {toc}{#1}%
        {\ifnum #2>\c@secnumdepth \else
        \protect\numberline {\csname the#1\endcsname}\fi
        \protect\RL {#7}}}% \@svsechd
\fi \a@xsect {#5}}

%%%%%240999
%%%
%    ****************************************
%    *         PAGE STYLES                  *
%    ****************************************

\if@twoside         % If two-sided printing.
 \def \ps@headings {% for arabic mode
        \let \@mkboth \markboth \def\@oddfoot{}\def\@evenfoot{}%
    \def \@evenhead {\edef \thepage {\nxp\RL{\thepage }}% left heading
                \leftmark \hfil \LR{\thepage} }% \LR 311098
        \def \@oddhead {\edef \thepage {\nxp\RL{\thepage}}% right heading
        \def \chaptermark ##1{\markboth {##1%
                \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
                \if@mainmatter
                 \hskip 1em\relax \RL{\@chapapp \space \thechapter  }%
                \fi\fi }{}}%
        \def \sectionmark ##1{\markleft {##1\ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\@ne
                \hskip 1em\relax \RL{\thesection}\fi }}%
        \ifa@article
      \def \subsectionmark ##1{\markleft {##1\ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\@ne
                \hskip 1em\relax \RL{\thesubsection }\fi }}%
        \fi }
\else               % If one-sided printing.
\def \ps@headings {% for arabic mode
        \let \@mkboth \markboth \def \@oddfoot{}\def \@evenfoot{}%
        \def \@oddhead {\edef \thepage {\nxp \LR{\thepage}}% right heading
                \LR{\thepage} \hfil \rightmark }%
        \def \chaptermark ##1{\markright {##1%
                \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
                \if@mainmatter
                \hskip 1em\relax \RL{\@chapapp\space $\thechapter$  }%
                \fi\fi }}}
\fi

\def \ps@plain {% for arabic mode
 \let \@mkboth\@gobbletwo \let\@oddhead\@empty \let\@evenhead\@empty
   \def \@oddfoot {\edef \thepage {\nxp\LR{ \thepage }}% right heading
                \hfil \LR{\thepage} \hfil }%
        \let \@evenfoot\@oddfoot }

\def \ps@myheadings {% for arabic mode
        \let\@oddfoot \@empty \let\@evenfoot \@empty
        \def \@oddhead {\edef \thepage {\nxp \LR{\thepage }}% right heading
               \LR{\thepage} \hfil \rightmark }%
        \def \@evenhead {\edef \thepage {\nxp\LR{\thepage }}% left heading
                \leftmark \hfil \LR{\thepage} }%
        \let\@mkboth\@gobbletwo \let\subsectionmark\@gobble
        \let\chaptermark\@gobble \let\sectionmark\@gobble }
%%%%ktAbT al-.sf.hT al-'awlY mn al-bAb wrqmh
\def\a@makechapterhead #1{% make heading with number
\null \vskip 50\p@
\begingroup \let \end \a@@par \a@@raggedright \interlinepenalty\@M
\ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
\if@mainmatter
        \edef \thechapter {\@chapapp \space \LR{\thechapter}  }%
        \huge \nashbf \set@arabfont \test@token {\thechapter } \end
        \nobreak \vskip 20\p@
\fi\fi
        \Huge \nashbf \set@arabfont \test@token #1 \end
        \nobreak \vskip 40\p@
\endgroup }

%%%%*********************************************************************
\ifa@book
 \renewcommand\theequation{\@arabic\c@equation.\@arabic\c@chapter}
\pagestyle{headings}
\else
\pagestyle{plain}
\fi
\pagenumbering{arabic}

\if@twoside
\else \raggedbottom
\fi

\if@twocolumn \twocolumn \sloppy \flushbottom
\else \onecolumn
\fi

%\else %============= arabart.cls ==================================

% Default initializations

\ifa@book \pagestyle{headings} \else \pagestyle{plain} \fi
\pagenumbering{arabic}      % Arabic page numbers

%    ****************************************
\catcode`\@=\active
```

Comment: you want to do this for all chapters or just for the introduction?

Comment: For all the chapters please @touhami

Comment: by the way, It seems that you have a problem in the header, because of fancyhdr. I will try to check this for you later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution. We need to redefine `\a@makechapterhead` command, like this

```
\def\a@makechapterhead #1{% make heading with number
\null \vfil
\begingroup \let \end \a@@par \a@@centering \interlinepenalty\@M
\ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
\if@mainmatter
        \edef \thechapter {\LR{\ahhrule}\@chapapp \space\arabicwords{chapter} \LR{\ahhrule}}%
        \huge \nashbf \set@arabfont \test@token {\thechapter } \end
        %\nobreak \vskip 10\p@
\fi\fi 
\hrule width \linewidth height 1pt \vskip10pt
        \Huge \nashbf \set@arabfont \test@token #1 \end
\vskip10pt\hrule width \linewidth height 1pt
\endgroup \vfil\newpage}
```

**Note 1** don't use `\newpage` after `\chapter{...}` in the body.

**MWE**

```
\documentclass[12pt]{arabbook} %{arabart},oneside
\usepackage{amsfonts,amssymb,amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{arqam}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{color}
\novocalize
%\parskip 0mm
%\setcounter{page}{1}\setcounter{chapter}{1}
\mathchardef\cap="225C
%\dominitoc \linespread{1.5} \setlength{\hoffset}{-18pt}
\textwidth=17.5truecm
\hoffset=-2truecm 
\textheight=24truecm
\voffset=-3truecm 
\newcommand{\vc}[3]{\overset{#2}{\underset{#3}{#1}}}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter 
\newcommand{\arabic@words}[1]{
    \ifcase#1\or 
    Al'awl\or 
    Al_tAny\or 
    Al_tAlt\or
    AlrAb`\or
    Al_hms\or
    AlsAds
    \else\@ctrerr\fi}
\newcommand*\arabicwords[1]{\expandafter\arabic@words\csname c@#1\endcsname}
\def \a@chapter [#1]#2{% numbered chapter
    \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
    \if@mainmatter
    \refstepcounter {chapter}%
    \typeout {\@chapapp \space \thechapter.}%
    \addcontentsline {toc}{chapter}%
    {\protect\numberline {\@chapapp\space\arabicwords{chapter}:}\protect\RL {#1}}%
    \else \addcontentsline {toc}{chapter}{\protect\RL {#1}}%
    \fi          
    \else \addcontentsline {toc}{chapter}{\protect\RL {#1}}%
    \fi
    \chaptermark{\RL {#1}}%
    \addtocontents {lof}{\protect\addvspace {10\p@}}%
    \addtocontents {lot}{\protect\addvspace {10\p@}}%
    \if@twocolumn \@topnewpage [\a@makechapterhead {#2}]%
    \else \a@makechapterhead {#2}\a@afterheading
    \fi 
    \tracingmacros 0
    \test@token }

\newcommand{\ahhrule}{\leavevmode\leaders\hrule height 5pt\hfill\kern\z@}
\def\a@makechapterhead #1{% make heading with number
\null \vfil
\begingroup \let \end \a@@par \a@@centering \interlinepenalty\@M
\ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
\if@mainmatter
        \edef \thechapter {\LR{\ahhrule}\@chapapp \space\arabicwords{chapter} \LR{\ahhrule}}%
        \huge \nashbf \set@arabfont \test@token {\thechapter } \end
        %\nobreak \vskip 10\p@
\fi\fi 
\hrule width \linewidth height 1pt \vskip10pt
        \Huge \nashbf \set@arabfont \test@token #1 \end
\vskip10pt\hrule width \linewidth height 1pt
\endgroup \vfil\newpage}    

\def \a@l@chapter #1#2{% for arabic mode
    \ifnum \c@tocdepth >\m@ne
    \addpenalty {-\@highpenalty }\addvspace {1.0em plus\p@ }
    \@tempdima 4em 
    \begin{arabtext}
        \hskip .7\@tempdima #1 \hfill  \LR{#2}
    \end{arabtext}
    \penalty\@highpenalty
    \fi }

\at@arabtext{%
    \def \l@section #1#2{% for arabic mode
        \ifnum \c@tocdepth >\z@
        \addpenalty {\@secpenalty }
        \@tempdima 2.8em 
        \begin{arabtext}
            \hskip \@tempdima #1 \LR{\dotfill}\LR{#2}
        \end{arabtext}
        \penalty\@secpenalty
        \fi }}
\at@arabtext{%
    \def \l@subsection #1#2{% for arabic mode
        \ifnum \c@tocdepth >\z@
        \addpenalty {\@secpenalty }
        \@tempdima 2.8em 
        \begin{arabtext}
            \hskip \@tempdima #1 \LR{\dotfill}\LR{#2}
        \end{arabtext}
        \penalty\@secpenalty
        \fi }}
\at@arabtext{%
    \def \l@subsubsection #1#2{% for arabic mode
        \ifnum \c@tocdepth >\z@
        \addpenalty {\@secpenalty }
        \@tempdima 2.8em 
        \begin{arabtext}
            \hskip \@tempdima #1 \LR{\dotfill}\LR{#2}
        \end{arabtext}
        \penalty\@secpenalty
        \fi }}
\makeatother

\renewcommand{\thesection}{\LR\arabic{section}}
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\LR\arabic{section}.\LR\arabic{subsection}}
\renewcommand{\thesubsubsection}{\LR\arabic{section}.\LR\arabic{subsection}.\LR\arabic{subsubsection}}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}


\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{1.5pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{1.5pt}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1}



\begin{document}
\begin{arabtext}


\tableofcontents

\chapter{mkdmT}

hnA n.s Alf.sl Al'awl


\end{arabtext}
\end{document}
```

---

**Edit** following the comments here is a modified mwe

```
\documentclass[12pt]{arabbook} %{arabart},oneside
\usepackage{amsfonts,amssymb,amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{arqam}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{color}
\novocalize
%\parskip 0mm
%\setcounter{page}{1}\setcounter{chapter}{1}
\mathchardef\cap="225C
%\dominitoc \linespread{1.5} \setlength{\hoffset}{-18pt}
\textwidth=17.5truecm
\hoffset=-2truecm 
\textheight=24truecm
\voffset=-3truecm 
\newcommand{\vc}[3]{\overset{#2}{\underset{#3}{#1}}}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter 
\newcommand{\arabic@words}[1]{
    \ifcase#1\or 
    Al'awl\or 
    Al_tAny\or 
    Al_tAlt\or
    AlrAb`\or
    Al_hms\or
    AlsAds
    \else\@ctrerr\fi}
\newcommand*\arabicwords[1]{\expandafter\arabic@words\csname c@#1\endcsname}
\def \a@chapter [#1]#2{% numbered chapter
    \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
    \if@mainmatter
    \refstepcounter {chapter}%
    \typeout {\@chapapp \space \thechapter.}%
    \addcontentsline {toc}{chapter}%
    {\protect\numberline {\@chapapp\space\arabicwords{chapter}:}\protect\RL {#1}}%
    \else \addcontentsline {toc}{chapter}{\protect\RL {#1}}%
    \fi          
    \else \addcontentsline {toc}{chapter}{\protect\RL {#1}}%
    \fi
    \chaptermark{\RL {#1}}%
    \addtocontents {lof}{\protect\addvspace {10\p@}}%
    \addtocontents {lot}{\protect\addvspace {10\p@}}%
    \if@twocolumn \@topnewpage [\a@makechapterhead {#2}]%
    \else \a@makechapterhead {#2}\a@afterheading
    \fi 
    \tracingmacros 0
    \test@token }

\newcommand{\ahhrule}{\leavevmode\leaders\hrule height 5pt\hfill\kern\z@}
\def\a@makechapterhead #1{% make heading with number
\begingroup \let \end \a@@par \a@@centering \interlinepenalty\@M
\ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
\if@mainmatter
        \edef \thechapter {\LR{\ahhrule}\@chapapp \space\arabicwords{chapter} \LR{\ahhrule}}%
        \huge \nashbf \set@arabfont \test@token {\thechapter } \end
        %\nobreak \vskip 10\p@
\fi\fi 
\hrule width \linewidth height 1pt \vfil
        \Huge \nashbf \set@arabfont \test@token #1 \end
\endgroup \vfil\hrule width \linewidth height 1pt\pagebreak}    

\def \a@l@chapter #1#2{% for arabic mode
    \ifnum \c@tocdepth >\m@ne
    \addpenalty {-\@highpenalty }\addvspace {1.0em plus\p@ }
    \@tempdima 4em 
    \begin{arabtext}
        \hskip .7\@tempdima #1 \hfill  \LR{#2}
    \end{arabtext}
    \penalty\@highpenalty
    \fi }

\at@arabtext{%
    \def \l@section #1#2{% for arabic mode
        \ifnum \c@tocdepth >\z@
        \addpenalty {\@secpenalty }
        \@tempdima 2.8em 
        \begin{arabtext}
            \hskip \@tempdima #1 \LR{\dotfill}\LR{#2}
        \end{arabtext}
        \penalty\@secpenalty
        \fi }}
\at@arabtext{%
    \def \l@subsection #1#2{% for arabic mode
        \ifnum \c@tocdepth >\z@
        \addpenalty {\@secpenalty }
        \@tempdima 2.8em 
        \begin{arabtext}
            \hskip \@tempdima #1 \LR{\dotfill}\LR{#2}
        \end{arabtext}
        \penalty\@secpenalty
        \fi }}
\at@arabtext{%
    \def \l@subsubsection #1#2{% for arabic mode
        \ifnum \c@tocdepth >\z@
        \addpenalty {\@secpenalty }
        \@tempdima 2.8em 
        \begin{arabtext}
            \hskip \@tempdima #1 \LR{\dotfill}\LR{#2}
        \end{arabtext}
        \penalty\@secpenalty
        \fi }}
\makeatother

\renewcommand{\thesection}{\LR\arabic{section}}
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\LR\arabic{section}.\LR\arabic{subsection}}
\renewcommand{\thesubsubsection}{\LR\arabic{section}.\LR\arabic{subsection}.\LR\arabic{subsubsection}}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}


\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{1.5pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{1.5pt}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1}



\begin{document}
\begin{arabtext}


\tableofcontents

\chapter{mkdmT}

hnA n.s Alf.sl Al'awl


\end{arabtext}
\end{document}
```

**Edit:** Here is the heading between 2 rules vertically centered.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{arabbook} %{arabart},oneside
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{arqam}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{color}
\novocalize
%\parskip 0mm
%\setcounter{page}{1}\setcounter{chapter}{1}
\mathchardef\cap="225C
%\dominitoc \linespread{1.5} \setlength{\hoffset}{-18pt}
\textwidth=17.5truecm
\hoffset=-2truecm 
\textheight=24truecm
\voffset=-3truecm 
\newcommand{\vc}[3]{\overset{#2}{\underset{#3}{#1}}}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter 
\newcommand{\arabic@words}[1]{
    \ifcase#1\or 
    Al'awl\or 
    Al_tAny\or 
    Al_tAlt\or
    AlrAb`\or
    Al_hms\or
    AlsAds
    \else\@ctrerr\fi}
\newcommand*\arabicwords[1]{\expandafter\arabic@words\csname c@#1\endcsname}
\def \a@chapter [#1]#2{% numbered chapter
    \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
    \if@mainmatter
    \refstepcounter {chapter}%
    \typeout {\@chapapp \space \thechapter.}%
    \addcontentsline {toc}{chapter}%
    {\protect\numberline {\@chapapp\space\arabicwords{chapter}:}\protect\RL {#1}}%
    \else \addcontentsline {toc}{chapter}{\protect\RL {#1}}%
    \fi          
    \else \addcontentsline {toc}{chapter}{\protect\RL {#1}}%
    \fi
    \chaptermark{\RL {#1}}%
    \addtocontents {lof}{\protect\addvspace {10\p@}}%
    \addtocontents {lot}{\protect\addvspace {10\p@}}%
    \if@twocolumn \@topnewpage [\a@makechapterhead {#2}]%
    \else \a@makechapterhead {#2}\a@afterheading
    \fi 
    \tracingmacros 0
    \test@token }

\newcommand{\ahhrule}{\leavevmode\leaders\hrule height 5pt\hfill\kern\z@}
\def\a@makechapterhead #1{% make heading with number
\begingroup \let \end \a@@par \a@@centering \interlinepenalty\@M
\ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
\if@mainmatter
        \edef \thechapter {\LR{\ahhrule}\@chapapp \space\arabicwords{chapter} \LR{\ahhrule}}%
        \huge \nashbf \set@arabfont \test@token {\thechapter } \end
        %\nobreak \vskip 10\p@
\fi\fi 
%********************** top rule
\hrule width \linewidth height 1pt 
\vfil
%********************** above
\hrule width \linewidth height 1pt
\vskip10pt
%********************** 
        \Huge \nashbf \set@arabfont \test@token #1 \end
\endgroup 
%********************** below
\vskip10pt 
\hrule width \linewidth height 1pt
%********************** below
\vfil
%********************** bottom rule
\hrule width \linewidth height 1pt
\pagebreak}    

\def \a@l@chapter #1#2{% for arabic mode
    \ifnum \c@tocdepth >\m@ne
    \addpenalty {-\@highpenalty }\addvspace {1.0em plus\p@ }
    \@tempdima 4em 
    \begin{arabtext}
        \hskip .7\@tempdima #1 \hfill  \LR{#2}
    \end{arabtext}
    \penalty\@highpenalty
    \fi }

\at@arabtext{%
    \def \l@section #1#2{% for arabic mode
        \ifnum \c@tocdepth >\z@
        \addpenalty {\@secpenalty }
        \@tempdima 2.8em 
        \begin{arabtext}
            \hskip \@tempdima #1 \LR{\dotfill}\LR{#2}
        \end{arabtext}
        \penalty\@secpenalty
        \fi }}
\at@arabtext{%
    \def \l@subsection #1#2{% for arabic mode
        \ifnum \c@tocdepth >\z@
        \addpenalty {\@secpenalty }
        \@tempdima 2.8em 
        \begin{arabtext}
            \hskip \@tempdima #1 \LR{\dotfill}\LR{#2}
        \end{arabtext}
        \penalty\@secpenalty
        \fi }}
\at@arabtext{%
    \def \l@subsubsection #1#2{% for arabic mode
        \ifnum \c@tocdepth >\z@
        \addpenalty {\@secpenalty }
        \@tempdima 2.8em 
        \begin{arabtext}
            \hskip \@tempdima #1 \LR{\dotfill}\LR{#2}
        \end{arabtext}
        \penalty\@secpenalty
        \fi }}
\makeatother

\renewcommand{\thesection}{\LR\arabic{section}}
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\LR\arabic{section}.\LR\arabic{subsection}}
\renewcommand{\thesubsubsection}{\LR\arabic{section}.\LR\arabic{subsection}.\LR\arabic{subsubsection}}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}


\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{1.5pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{1.5pt}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1}



\begin{document}
\begin{arabtext}


\tableofcontents

\chapter{mkdmT}

hnA n.s Alf.sl Al'awl


\end{arabtext}
\end{document}
```

**EDIT**
You need to add this

```
\def \a@t@ble #1#2{% \tableofcontents etc.
\null \vskip 10\p@ 
\begingroup \let \end \a@@par \a@@centering \interlinepenalty\@M
    \a@normalfont \Huge \bfseries \set@arabfont \test@token #1 \end
\endgroup
\vskip10pt 
\hrule width \linewidth height 2pt
\nobreak \vskip 20\p@ 
\@mkboth {#1}{#1}\a@c@starttoc {#2}}
```

Here is a complete example

```
\documentclass[12pt]{arabbook} %{arabart},oneside
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{arqam}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{color}
\novocalize
%\parskip 0mm
%\setcounter{page}{1}\setcounter{chapter}{1}
\mathchardef\cap="225C
%\dominitoc \linespread{1.5} \setlength{\hoffset}{-18pt}
\textwidth=17.5truecm
\hoffset=-2truecm 
\textheight=24truecm
\voffset=-3truecm 
\newcommand{\vc}[3]{\overset{#2}{\underset{#3}{#1}}}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter 
\newcommand{\arabic@words}[1]{
    \ifcase#1\or 
    Al'awl\or 
    Al_tAny\or 
    Al_tAlt\or
    AlrAb`\or
    Al_hms\or
    AlsAds
    \else\@ctrerr\fi}
\newcommand*\arabicwords[1]{\expandafter\arabic@words\csname c@#1\endcsname}
\def \a@chapter [#1]#2{% numbered chapter
    \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
    \if@mainmatter
    \refstepcounter {chapter}%
    \typeout {\@chapapp \space \thechapter.}%
    \addcontentsline {toc}{chapter}%
    {\protect\numberline {\@chapapp\space\arabicwords{chapter}:}\protect\RL {#1}}%
    \else \addcontentsline {toc}{chapter}{\protect\RL {#1}}%
    \fi          
    \else \addcontentsline {toc}{chapter}{\protect\RL {#1}}%
    \fi
    \chaptermark{\RL {#1}}%
    \addtocontents {lof}{\protect\addvspace {10\p@}}%
    \addtocontents {lot}{\protect\addvspace {10\p@}}%
    \if@twocolumn \@topnewpage [\a@makechapterhead {#2}]%
    \else \a@makechapterhead {#2}\a@afterheading
    \fi 
    \tracingmacros 0
    \test@token }

\newcommand{\ahhrule}{\leavevmode\leaders\hrule height 5pt\hfill\kern\z@}
\def\a@makechapterhead #1{% make heading with number
\begingroup \let \end \a@@par \a@@centering \interlinepenalty\@M
\ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
\if@mainmatter
        \edef \thechapter {\LR{\ahhrule}\@chapapp \space\arabicwords{chapter} \LR{\ahhrule}}%
        \huge \nashbf \set@arabfont \test@token {\thechapter } \end
        %\nobreak \vskip 10\p@
\fi\fi 
%********************** top rule
\hrule width \linewidth height 1pt 
\vfil
%********************** above
\hrule width \linewidth height 1pt
\vskip10pt
%********************** 
        \Huge \nashbf \set@arabfont \test@token #1 \end
\endgroup 
%********************** below
\vskip10pt 
\hrule width \linewidth height 1pt
%********************** below
\vfil
%********************** bottom rule
\hrule width \linewidth height 1pt
\pagebreak} 

\def\a@makeschapterhead #1{%
\null \vskip 50\p@ 
\begingroup \let \end \a@@par \a@@centering \interlinepenalty\@M
    \a@normalfont \Huge \bfseries \set@arabfont \test@token #1 \end
\endgroup
\nobreak \vskip 40\p@ } 

\def \a@t@ble #1#2{% \tableofcontents etc.
\null \vskip 10\p@ 
\begingroup \let \end \a@@par \a@@centering \interlinepenalty\@M
    \a@normalfont \Huge \bfseries \set@arabfont \test@token #1 \end
\endgroup
\vskip10pt 
\hrule width \linewidth height 2pt
\nobreak \vskip 20\p@ 
\@mkboth {#1}{#1}\a@c@starttoc {#2}}



\def \a@l@chapter #1#2{% for arabic mode
    \ifnum \c@tocdepth >\m@ne
    \addpenalty {-\@highpenalty }\addvspace {1.0em plus\p@ }
    \@tempdima 4em 
    \begin{arabtext}
        \hskip .7\@tempdima #1 \hfill  \LR{#2}
    \end{arabtext}
    \penalty\@highpenalty
    \fi }

\at@arabtext{%
    \def \l@section #1#2{% for arabic mode
        \ifnum \c@tocdepth >\z@
        \addpenalty {\@secpenalty }
        \@tempdima 2.8em 
        \begin{arabtext}
            \hskip \@tempdima #1 \LR{\dotfill}\LR{#2}
        \end{arabtext}
        \penalty\@secpenalty
        \fi }}
\at@arabtext{%
    \def \l@subsection #1#2{% for arabic mode
        \ifnum \c@tocdepth >\z@
        \addpenalty {\@secpenalty }
        \@tempdima 2.8em 
        \begin{arabtext}
            \hskip \@tempdima #1 \LR{\dotfill}\LR{#2}
        \end{arabtext}
        \penalty\@secpenalty
        \fi }}
\at@arabtext{%
    \def \l@subsubsection #1#2{% for arabic mode
        \ifnum \c@tocdepth >\z@
        \addpenalty {\@secpenalty }
        \@tempdima 2.8em 
        \begin{arabtext}
            \hskip \@tempdima #1 \LR{\dotfill}\LR{#2}
        \end{arabtext}
        \penalty\@secpenalty
        \fi }}
\makeatother

\renewcommand{\thesection}{\LR\arabic{section}}
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\LR\arabic{section}.\LR\arabic{subsection}}
\renewcommand{\thesubsubsection}{\LR\arabic{section}.\LR\arabic{subsection}.\LR\arabic{subsubsection}}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}


\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{1.5pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{1.5pt}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1}



\begin{document}

\catcode`\@=11 \let\tableofcontents\a@c@tableofcontents \catcode`\@=12

\begin{arabtext}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{mkdmT}

hnA n.s Alf.sl Al'awl


\end{arabtext}
\end{document}
```

Comment: can I put in the center just the name of the chapter "chapter one" in the top of the page and the title in the center" @touhami

Comment: @PolineSandra what about the 3 fancy rules?

Comment: to get a line in the top of the page and a line in the end of each page at each chapter a write the same thing @touhami

Comment: @PolineSandra answer modified.

Comment: what is the commande you change @touhami

Comment: @PolineSandra it's `\def\a@makechapterhead #1{...`

Comment: please if I want to make mqdmT under two lines what I must added please

Comment: @PolineSandra i can't see what do you mean.

Comment: I want to make the title of the chapter into two lines

Comment: I want to make the title of the chapter in the middle between two lines

Comment: you understand what I say @touhami ?

Comment: I will try to add this and we will see :-)

Comment: I think you forget me @touhami

Comment: @PolineSandra no. But it's my computer, sorry. I'll try from another place as soon as possible.

Comment: Ah I'm sorry I don't know @touhami thank you

Comment: @PolineSandra answer updated.

Comment: thank you very much may God gives you all that you want @touhami

Comment: @PolineSandra you're welcome.

Comment: please I want to make a line under tableofcontents and write (محتويات) in the center is it possible ?

Comment: @PolineSandra i'll see tomorrow, i don't have time now.

Comment: thank you very much @touhami

Comment: if you prefer I can ask a new question

Comment: @PolineSandra No need I edited my answer.

Comment: I get an error @touhami :"file ended while scanning use of \contentsline line156

Comment: I added the first part and now it works

Comment: please @touhami have you an idea about this question:https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/524548/colored-chapter-and-toc