# Colored chapter and toc

Tags: table-of-contents, xetex, color, chapters

How to obtain this format:

[image]

and this

[image]

```
 \documentclass[12pt,a4paper,openany]{book}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{titleps}
\usepackage{pifont}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm}
\usepackage{geometry}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns,shapes.geometric}
\linespread{1.5} 
\usetikzlibrary{calc, hobby}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newtheoremstyle{break}% name
  {}%         Space above, empty = `usual value'
  {}%         Space below
  {\itshape}% Body font
  {}%         Indent amount (empty = no indent, \parindent = para indent)
  {\bfseries}% Thm head font
  {.}%        Punctuation after thm head
  {\newline}% Space after thm head: \newline = linebreak
  {}%         Thm head spec
\theoremstyle{break}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\newtheorem{theo}{نظرية}[section]
\newtheorem{theorem}{مبرهنة}[section]
\newtheorem{corollary}{نتيجة}[section]
\newtheorem{definition}{تعريف}[section]
\newtheorem{prop}{قضية}[section]
\newtheorem{proposition}{لازمة}[section]
\newtheorem{lemma}{توطئة}[section]
\newtheorem{remark}{ملاحظة}[section]
\newtheorem{example}{مثال}[section]
\newtheorem{exercise}{تمرين}[section]
\renewenvironment{proof}{{\bfseries برهان: $~~$\\}{}}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage[numerals=maghrib]{arabic}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic,Scale=1.1,AutoFakeSlant=-0.03]{Amiri}
\setsansfont[Script=Arabic,Scale=1.1]{Amiri}

\makeatletter
\pretocmd{\@chapter}{\begingroup \renewcommand{\thechapter}{{\words{chapter}}}}{}{}
\apptocmd{\@chapter}{\endgroup}{}{}
\makeatother
\titlecontents{lsection}
  [2.3em]{\LARGE}{\contentslabel{2.3em}}
  {\hspace*{-3em}}
  {}
\titlecontents{lsubsection}
  [4.6em]{\LARGE}{\contentslabel{2.3em}}
  {\hspace*{-3em}}
  {}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\normalfont\huge\bfseries}{\chaptertitlename\ \words{chapter}}{20pt}{\Huge}
\titlespacing{\chapter}
  {0pt}{40pt}{-10pt}



%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%  MACRO FOR LITERAL NUMBERING %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newcommand\words[1]{\expandafter\xwords\csname c@#1\endcsname}
\def\xwords#1{\ifcase#1\or
الأول\or
الثاني\or
الثالث\or
الرابع\or
الخامس\or
السادس\or
السابع\or
الثامن\or
التاسع\or
العاشر\or
الحادي عشر\or
الثاني عشر\or
الثالث عشر\or
الرابع عشر\or
الخامس عشر\or
السادس عشر\or
السابع عشر\or
الثامن عشر\or
التاسع عشر\or
العشرون\or
\else
I need more words\fi}

\makeatletter
%\patchcmd{\@makechapterhead}{\thechapter}{\words{chapter}}{}{}
\makeatother

\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.1}%المسافة بين الأسطر
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%  END MACRO FOR LITERAL NUMBERING %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%     REDEFINING NAMES IN ARABIC      %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\gappto\captionsarabic{\renewcommand{\contentsname}{المحتويات}}
\gappto\captionsarabic{\renewcommand{\chaptername}{الفصل}}
\gappto\captionsarabic{\def\figurename{رسم}}
\gappto\captionsarabic{\renewcommand{\tablename}{جدول}}
\gappto\captionsarabic{\renewcommand{\indexname}{\textbf{الثبت}}}
\gappto\captionsarabic{\renewcommand{\appendixname}{\textbf{الملحق}}}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%   MACRO FOR PARTIAL CONTENTS     %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%   END MACRO FOR PARTIAL CONTENTS     %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}%pour la numérotation dans le corps du document
%\setcounter{tocdepth}{5} %pour l'apparition dans la table des matières



%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% REDEFINES \THECHAPTER IN CONTENTS
\makeatletter
\pretocmd{\@chapter}{\begingroup \renewcommand{\thechapter}{{\words{chapter}}}}{}{}
\apptocmd{\@chapter}{\endgroup}{}{}
\makeatother
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% \usepackage{titletoc}%
\titlecontents{chapter}% <section-type>
  [0pt]% <left>
  {\bfseries\vspace*{10pt}}% <above-code>
  {\normalsize\chaptername\ \thecontentslabel.\;}% <numbered-entry-format>
  {}% <numberless-entry-format>
  {\normalsize\hfill\contentspage}% <filler-page-format>

\usepackage[Glenn]{fncychap}
\ChNumVar{\Large}% Dimension of the number of the chapter in the first page... instead of the default...\ChNumVar{\Huge}

\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}
\parindent=0mm





\begin{document}
\setnonlatin


\chapter{مقدمة }

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please can you make your code complete? `...\end{document}`

Comment: i edited my message @touhami

Comment: OK. I'll try. I suppose you want to do that for arabic text no?

Comment: yes of course @touhami thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution. It seems to be easier with etoc's package.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,openany]{book}
%-------------------------------------------------------
\usepackage{etoc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows}
%-------------------------------------------------------
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage[numerals=maghrib]{arabic}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic,Scale=1.1,AutoFakeSlant=-0.03]{Amiri}
\setsansfont[Script=Arabic,Scale=1.1]{Amiri}
%-------------------------------------------------------
\definecolor{myblue}{rgb}{0, .55, .7}
\newcommand*{\CircleNum}[1]{%
    \tikz[baseline={([yshift=-.5ex]current bounding box.center)}]
        \node[fill=myblue,circle,text=white] {#1};}
\newcommand*{\tocframe}[1]{%
    \hspace{.45\textwidth}\tikz\node[color=white, fill=myblue, drop shadow={opacity=.3},
        inner sep=5mm, rounded corners, font=\small]{%
            \parbox{.65\textwidth}{#1}};}
\newcommand*{\chapternumberbox}[1]{%
    \tikz\node[color=white, fill=blue!50!black, draw=black,
    rounded corners, inner sep=4pt, minimum height=2cm, font=\bfseries]{%
    \parbox{.18\textwidth}{\begin{Arabic}#1\end{Arabic}}};}
\newcommand{\chapternamebox}[1]{%
    \tikz\node[color=white, left color=blue!20!white, right color=blue, draw=gray,
        rounded corners, inner sep=4pt, minimum height=2cm, font=\bfseries]{%
            \parbox{.8\textwidth}{\begin{Arabic}#1\end{Arabic}}};}
\newcommand*{\chaptertoc}{%
    \begingroup
    \etocsettocstyle{}{}
    \etocsetstyle{section}{}{}
    {\etocsavedsectiontocline{\hskip-.5cm\numberline{\etocnumber}\etocname}{\textcolor{white}{\etocpage}}}{}%
    \etocsetstyle{subsection}{}{}
    {\etocsavedsubsectiontocline{\hskip-.5cm\numberline{\etocnumber}\etocname}{\textcolor{white}{\etocpage}}}{}%
    \etocsetstyle{subsubsection}{}{}
    {\etocsavedsubsubsectiontocline{\hskip-.5cm\numberline{\etocnumber}\etocname}{\textcolor{white}{\etocpage}}}{}%
    \tocframe{\localtableofcontents}
    \endgroup}
\makeatletter 
\def\@makechapterhead#1{%
  \vspace*{50\p@}%
  {\parindent \z@ \raggedleft \normalfont
    \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
      \if@mainmatter
        \hfill\huge\bfseries\color{myblue} \@chapapp\space \CircleNum{\thechapter}
        \par\nobreak
        \vskip 5\p@\rule{\textwidth}{1pt}\vskip 5\p@
      \fi
    \fi
    \interlinepenalty\@M
    \huge \bfseries #1\par\nobreak
    \vskip 15\p@ }
    \chaptertoc \vskip 10\p@}

\newcommand*{\mytableofcontents}{%
    \etocstandarddisplaystyle
    \etocsetstyle{part}{}{}
    {\etocsavedparttocline{\numberline{\etocnumber}\etocname}{\etocpage}}{}%
    \etocsetstyle{chapter}{}{\addvspace{10pt}\leftskip-5pt}
    {\leavevmode\chapternumberbox{\@chapapp\space\etocnumber}%
        \chapternamebox{\etocname\hfill\makebox[-20pt]{\etocpage}}}{}%
    \etocsetstyle{section}{}{}
    {\etocsavedsectiontocline{\numberline{\etocnumber}\etocname}{\etocpage}}{}%
    \etocsetstyle{subsection}{}{}
    {\etocsavedsubsectiontocline{\numberline{\etocnumber}\etocname}{\etocpage}}{}%
    \etocsetstyle{subsubsection}{}{}
    {\etocsavedsubsubsectiontocline{\numberline{\etocnumber}\etocname}{\etocpage}}{}%
    \tableofcontents}
\makeatother
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}          
%\setcounter{tocdepth}{5}           
%-------------------------------------------------------
%       REDEFINING NAMES IN ARABIC                     %
%-------------------------------------------------------
\gappto\captionsarabic{%
    \renewcommand{\contentsname}{المحتويات}
    \renewcommand{\chaptername}{الفصل}
    \def\figurename{رسم}
    \renewcommand{\tablename}{جدول}
    \renewcommand{\indexname}{\textbf{الثبت}}
    \renewcommand{\appendixname}{\textbf{الملحق}}}
%-------------------------------------------------------
\newtheorem{theo}{نظرية}[section]
\newtheorem{theorem}{مبرهنة}[section]
\newtheorem{corollary}{نتيجة}[section]
\newtheorem{definition}{تعريف}[section]
\newtheorem{prop}{قضية}[section]
\newtheorem{proposition}{لازمة}[section]
\newtheorem{lemma}{توطئة}[section]
\newtheorem{remark}{ملاحظة}[section]
\newtheorem{example}{مثال}[section]
\newtheorem{exercise}{تمرين}[section]
%\renewenvironment{proof}{{\bfseries  برهان:} \par\noindent}{}
%-------------------------------------------------------
\setlength{\parindent}{0mm}
\linespread{1.5} 
%-------------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}
\mytableofcontents
\chapter{مقدمة في الحساب}
\section{مدخل لعلم العدد}

\end{document}
```

Comment: i have chapters with 10 sections how to make the small table contents into two columns ?